# Git Add Syntax, Issues Pushing to Remote Repo

Tags: git, addition

I cannot get the `git add` command to work. I have looked up the syntax several times, even did a git tutorial and can't understand why this command isn't working as it should. Doing `git add` does not track the file I specify and I therefore can't push to a remote repository. What am I doing wrong?![I've highlighted the name of the file, I'm typing `git add pymaceuticals.ipynb`, which is the name of the file I'm trying to add, and am currently in the folder that the file is located]

Begin Edits:*
There is no error message, but when I check to see if the file has been added with `git status`, it hasn't been added. However, an older version of the file with a slightly different name has been? Along with output png files generated by the file I'm trying to add.

I know the `git add` does not push to the repo (sorry if that was unclear). I was looking to verify that there wasn't any syntax other than the standard that I should be using `git add filename`. I'm doing:

```
git add file
git commit -m "description"
git push -u origin master (and this command is not working either and reads fatal in finding both the remote and local repos).
```

What would the syntax be in supplying a local and remote repo name? I am already in the local repo file and I thought the computer defaulted to your that should no repo be specified? I've seen syntax that read:

```
git push -u "local repo": "remote repo"
```

but I'm not sure what should be named in my case... This is what I clone to my computer when I'm given the option to clone my repo:

```
https://github.com/eoefelein/matplotlib-challenge.git
```

Would that URL be the name I use in specifying the remote repo... I'm thinking no because I tried and it didn't work.

Hope this additional info makes adds clarity to my original question!

Comment: I guess you should tell us if there's an error message of sorts? What makes you think it's not added? Checking with `git status`? What is the output? Add that stuff to the original question.

Comment: there are 3 steps for file getting to repository: _add_, _commit_, _push_. and ```.gitignore``` file can interfer with "add" step. what "git status" does show?

Comment: Maxim, yes those are the steps I'm doing. And checking on what's going on with git status. I haven't used git ignore since I can remember, but I have used git stash? Not since creating my file though... Would that be interfering? How would I verify that and if it was interfering, what would the command be to reverse that? Thank you guys so much!

Comment: How does the result of `git status` look like before and after `git add`? Try to separate the issues: don't commit or push; the first question is if you can successfully add the change to the index.

Answer (score 1):

The `git add` command doesn't push anything to your remote repository. Moreover, this command doesn't even commit any changes. This command just creates an index: starts tracking the changes that you may (or may not) commit and push.

The correct sequense should be:

```
git add pymaceuticals.ipynb
git add other.file
git commit -m "Specify your commit message"
git push origin
```

Comment: The only difference between your and my code is I do not specify a second git add command (the one with other.file). Would you be using that in the case of adding two separate files? I am only adding one and so was under the impression, I need do only one git add command. In terms of my git push command, I was doing git push -u origin master but didn't try just git push origin... I'll give that a shot!

Comment: @Erin The second `git add` is not needed: this is just an indication that you may add any number of changes to the commit. You need to provide more info: the full sequence of commands, the result of `git status` before and after, the same for `git log`, `git branch`, etc.